# Get view from SettingsPreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm trying to add a view log option to androids settings.apk but are having some difficulties. I've tested it in a stand-alone test app, and it works fine. However when adding it to the SettingsPreferenceFragment I get some problems. I need to get the instance of the current layout in order to add the TextView with the log content.

```
LinearLayout layout = ???

......

layout.addView(myTextView);
```

Or should I create a new layout, and ???